# ABPIo app deployed to ElasticBeanstalk give postgresql exception

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, abp

I tried to deploy an application written in Abp.io version 6 (MVC application) to AWS ElasticBeanstalk + Postgresql instance on AWS as well.

If I run the application from my local env with db pointing to the AWS instance, it works.

When I deploy it I got

```
 Failed to connect to 172.31.2.40:5432
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during connection attempt
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|193_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: at Npgsql.ConnectorPool.<Get>g__RentAsync|27_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SplitQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Failed to connect to 172.31.2.40:5432
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during connection attempt
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.ConnectAsync(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
Mar 17 20:52:14 ip-172-31-21-214 web: at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|193_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, Cancellat
```

Do I have to allow the IP of the web app to the rules of AWS ? Should I use the same internal network?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem `Failed to connect to 172.31.2.40:5432`

The answer is yes. you should use the same internal network to reach the DB.